# CI Database table query error Call to a member function get() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

Im currently getting used to Code Igniter and have tried to make a small fake cinema system on my own, i can easily add data to the database but being able to pull it back is causing issues with this error

My database is called codeigniter and the table is named movies

This is the controller

```
    <?php

class Cinema extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this -> load -> model("Cinema_model");

    }

    public function index() {
        $this -> load -> helper("form");
        $this -> load -> library("form_validation");

        // Validation Rules
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules("title", "Movie Name", "required");
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules("startTime", "Start", "required");
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules("endTime", "End", "required");
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules("cost", "Cost", "required");

        if ($this -> form_validation -> run() == false) {
            $this -> load -> view("cinema_add");
        } else {

            $this -> cinema_model -> insert_movie();
            $this -> load -> view("formsuccess");
        }
    }

    public function getFilms() {
        $data['movies'] = $this -> cinema_model -> getfilms();

        $this -> load -> view("cinemalistings", $data);
    }

}
?>
```

This is my model

```
<?php

class Cinema extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this -> load -> model("Cinema_model");

    }

    public function index() {
        $this -> load -> helper("form");
        $this -> load -> library("form_validation");

        // Validation Rules
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules("title", "Movie Name", "required");
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules("startTime", "Start", "required");
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules("endTime", "End", "required");
        $this -> form_validation -> set_rules("cost", "Cost", "required");

        if ($this -> form_validation -> run() == false) {
            $this -> load -> view("cinema_add");
        } else {

            $this -> cinema_model -> insert_movie();
            $this -> load -> view("formsuccess");
        }
    }

    public function getFilms() {
        $data['movies'] = $this -> cinema_model -> getfilms();

        $this -> load -> view("cinemalistings", $data);
    }

}
?>
```

My view

```
    <?php

print_r($movies);
?>
```

im sure the code is fine and when asked other people to look at it they said it should be fine but i keep getting met with an error when trying to load the getFilms page

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: Cinema::$cinema_model

Filename: controllers/cinema.php

Line Number: 30

Fatal error: Call to a member function getfilms() on a non-object in /opt/lampp/htdocs/cinema/application/controllers/cinema.php on line 30

i have also tried looking at other peoples examples to see if i were doing it right and changed code still same error

any helps

thanks

Comment: try `$this->load->model("cinema_model");`

Comment: first show me your model code.you posted here both controller code.

Comment: You wrote twice the controller code instead of posting the model also

Comment: user2023223............ changing it to $this->load->model("cinema_model") has got rid of the error but now the model is compaling of  Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_result::results_array() in /opt/lampp/htdocs/cinema/application/models/cinema_model.php on line 25

Comment: plz paste correct code for the model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_result::results_array() "

It's

```
result_array();
```

(no s) not

```
results_array()
```

Answer (score 1):

**You have a huge typo error**:
In MODEL:

```
class Cinema extends CI_MODEL {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this -> load -> model("Cinema_model");

    }
```